# Difference between a compound statement and a block in C++?

Tags: c++, scope, terminology, statements

I often hear about the term of "compound statements" almost interchangeably used for a block, starting and ending with curly brackets of `{}`. I see no differences to a block.

So my Question is:

- Is there a difference between a "block" and "compound statement"?

Answer (score 1):

To cite the actual C++ standard, *ISO/IEC 14882:2017 (C++17), Section 9.3 "Compound statement or block"*:

> 9.3 Compound statement or block [stmt.block]
>
> 1 So that several statements can be used where one is expected, **the compound statement (also, and equivalently, called “block”)** is provided.
>
> compound-statement: { statement-seqopt }

there is *no* difference between the terms of a block and a compound statement in their respective meaning.

You can use both terms interchangeably for a "compound" or sequence of statements (it may even be only one statement; the amount of statements doesn´t matter) starting by a "`{`" - opened curly bracket and terminating by a "`}`" - closed curly bracket.

Answer (score 0):

A "block" of code, delimited by `{ }` to indicate entry-exit points, limits the liftetime of any variables defined inside the block to that block, wheras a "compound statement" might not unless it uses `{ }` inside it. A function definition may be construed as a "named block" of code with an entry and exit points.